# Overlapping Date Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to display multiple dates on a screen. Currently, when a user clicks on a date button, it will open a datepicker. If the user clicks out of the box, the datepicker closes as it normally should react. But if the user clicks on another datepicker button, the datepicker will not close but instead, will open another datepicker window and overlap it. [I tried uploading a picture]

I am using Angular-UI for this. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
I believe this is a bug? Is there a quick hack to disable the first box when clicked on a different button?

Thank you!

EDIT:
code being used is here:

```
<div class="row">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dateTextField" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="search.minOrderTime" is-open="minordertime" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton" ng-click="openDate($event,'minordertime')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <b>Max Order Time:</b>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dateTextField" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="search.maxOrderTime" is-open="maxordertime" datepicker-options="dateOptions" min-date="minDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton" ng-click="openDate($event, 'maxordertime')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </p>

            </div>

            <b>min Last Modified:</b>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dateTextField" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="search.minLastModified" is-open="minlastmodified" datepicker-options="dateOptions" min-date="minDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton" ng-click="openDate($event, 'minlastmodified')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <b>Max Last Modified:</b>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dateTextField" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="search.maxLastModified" is-open="maxlastmodified" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton" ng-click="openDate($event,'maxlastmodified')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <b>Order Date:</b>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dateTextField" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="search.orderDate" is-open="orderdate" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton" ng-click="openDate($event,'orderdate')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $scope.openDate = function ($event, opened) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope[opened] = true;
};
```

Comment: Are you using the same variable for the `is-opened="<scope-variable>"` attribute? If you have a different one you shouldn't get this problem.

And you can attach an event handler to whatever you're clicking, like `<button ng-click="openNewDatepicker = true; openOtherDatepicker = false;">`

Comment: @azium I have updated the post to include how it us being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object to store which datepicker is currently open instead of directly on the `$scope`. That way when you open a new picker you can easily clear them all by writing `$scope.openPicker = {}` and assigning the new open one `$scope.openPicker[opened]`

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/18qJoEFnm2kzZYbErmwK?p=preview)

Just remember to change your `is-open` to include the object: `is-open="openPicker.yourPicker"`

Comment: Lifesaver. Great work! Agreed, object would make much more sense since I can clear it when clicked on a different button